# Can I test app on emulator with 1080p resolution?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I install visual studio 2013, but I can't run app on emulator with 1080p resolution.

Available only this emulators

```
<ScreenResolutions>
      <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_WVGA" />
      <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_HD720P" />
      <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_WXGA" />
    </ScreenResolutions>
```

How I can test my app for device with 1080p resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Emulator images for 1080p or GDR3 phones are not yet available, but they should be soon!
Anyway from your point of view the 1080p device has same scale factor as 720p devices, so if your app supports 720p devices, it should work just fine on 1080p devices as well.

In case you want to detect such devices or provide specific content, here's a nice article how to do it:
[Resolution specific considerations](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!optimising-for-large-screen-phones/resolution-specific-considerations.html)
Or here similar article on MSDN:
[Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, the support will be out soon.

But since 1080p is using the same aspect ration as 720p, you can "fake it" and pretend that 720p is actually 1080p and test in that environment. Besides, you won't really notice the difference anyway.

Comment: I don't understand how I can do it

Comment: If your application works on 720p it should work on 1080p without any changes. Unless you are using custom font sizes or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's available now, you can now run your WindowsPhone8 app in 1080p resolution emulator, Microsoft just released an update for it, read the [Windows Phone Developer Blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2014/01/02/new-emulators-available-for-windows-phone-8-0-updates-2-and-3.aspx)